# Tomcat7 Setup - CentOS 6.3

Tags: centos6, tomcat7

I have tomcat7 packages installed as follows

```
[root@mongos lib]# yum list installed | grep tomcat7
tomcat7.noarch          7.0.39-1.jpp6   @eng-support-jpackage                   
tomcat7-admin-webapps.noarch
tomcat7-el-2.2-api.noarch
tomcat7-jsp-2.2-api.noarch
tomcat7-lib.noarch      7.0.39-1.jpp6   @eng-support-jpackage                   
tomcat7-servlet-3.0-api.noarch
```

and enabled the manager web app.

It is my understanding that  tomcat7-servlet-3.0-api provides the needed Servlet 3.0 API for Java web apps.

Now when i deploy a war file using the manager app, tomcat cannot find the WebApplicationInitializer class which was introduced in Servlet 3.0 api that does away with the need of a web.xml file inside the war file.

Now i believe there is a problem in the tomcat7 setup.

To confirm my claim, i did the following.

If the same war file is deployed on a standalone tomcat7 downloaded from http://tomcat.apache.org, the application works fine.

Is anyone familiar on correct setup of tomcat7 on CentOS?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following bits of information helped me resolve the issue.

**/etc/sysconfig/tomcat7**

Ensure all the variables are accurate. Especially JAVA_HOME & CATALINA_HOME.

**Ownership of folders for tomcat user**

Ensure tomcat ownership for /var/log/tomcat7, /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps & /var/cache/tomcat7
In most cases, this should have been correct by the installation but could be in a weird state due to tomcat6 & tomcat7 multiple install.

**Correct Home folder for tomcat user**

The RPM based installation runs tomcat7 under the tomcat user. I had a previous installation of tomcat ( v6 ) and the user's home directory was set to ( **/usr/share/tomcat6** ). Upon install of tomcat7 and un-install of tomcat6 the correct folder was not set ( **/usr/share/tomcat7** ). This caused the lib folder under **/usr/share/tomcat7** to be not found causing problems loading my webapp. You need to edit **/etc/passwd** file and make tomcat user have the correct home directory.

**YMMV**